# Behavior of "Paste" command in WinForms app on Windows 7 (French)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Running "Paste" command in WinForms in webbrowser Win7(French).

I'm trying to copy and paste image in WinForms application in webbrowser using this command:

`webbrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Paste", false, null);`

It works fine on English or Chinese OS, but does not work on French OS.

Comment: Check the security level in IE options.

Comment: The french translation is "Coller" but not sure that's the issue or the solution. It should work tho

Comment: @xdtTransform I'm not sure either, but you can try it though.

Comment: @SᴇM, thanks, I've upgraded IE to version 11, and now it works fine.

Comment: @abc89 ok, good.